# Different transactions updates same data Spring AOP does a dirty update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-aop

I have an issue with Spring AOP which is trying to do a dirty update of same object in multiple transactions & I'm not able to catch the `staleobjectstateexception`.

I have a Spring rest method calls up on (HTTP delete ), which will receive a parameter & update the database. In the same call I also do couple of more updates. but the last object I update, get updated twice & throws `"optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)"`

When I tried debugging I found that the same object gets updated multiple times & throws the exception.

```
User user = retrieveUser(userId); 
user.cancelSubscription(regUser.getId(), responseDate); 
updateUser(user);  Message msg= createCancelSubscriptionMessage(user,
MessageType.SUBSCRPTION_CANCEL);
getMessagingDatamapper.sendMessageToUser(user,msg);
```

here the cancelled subscription transaction gets committed to user table  but the message transaction tries to update many times & fails

Error stack trace

```
org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to invoke handler
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:96)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:188)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.doInvoke(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:84)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:58)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:137)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:52)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:97)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: Expression evaluation failed: @messagingService.sendMessageToUser(headers.userId, payload)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:100)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.processMessage(ExpressionEvaluatingMessageProcessor.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:67)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:262)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$1.cloneAndExecute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:76)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice$2.doWithRetry(RequestHandlerRetryAdvice.java:87)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Object of class [domainModel.messaging.Message] with identifier [8108]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [domainModel.messaging.Message#8108]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:199)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:606)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:488)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:387)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.sendMessageToUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:69)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:84)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:57)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:102)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:86)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [model]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2368)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3020)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2918)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3247)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:140)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1214)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:403)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
... 48 more
```

any solutions

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post a little bit richer exception stack trace.

Comment: Could you paste some code of this updates?

Comment: Added some code snippet  let me know if you need some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of approaches you can take:

1. Wrap the HTTP DELETE code in a single transaction. This way you do not have to deal with stale objects across different transactions.
2. Do not pass an object modified in one transaction to a method that is invoked in another transaction. You can instead pass the id of the object to the method and load this object afresh there.

Comment: HTTP DELETE was the killer , We have 3 layer application all 3 had HTTP DELETE , The call goes from client to middleware to backend spring. I had the same doubt & I just tried changing the middleware to backend as POST & client was still communicating on DELETE it dint work out . Finally i changed all to POST . Now works . New learning that DELETE doesn't support multiple transactions .. 1 up for the life saver :)